# PHP remove all objects but one with same property from Array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using Eloquent, I want to remove 2 objects from the $outputs array with 'Title' B and keep only one.

$outputs has the following information:

```
[
    {
        "Title": "A",
        "Publication date": "2013",
    },
    {
        "Title": "B",
        "Publication date": "2010",
    },
    {
        "Title": "B",
        "Publication date": "2999",
    },
    {
        "Title": "B",
        "Publication date": "5555",
    },
];
```

I know there are plenty of posts about this but I couldn't find a way to do it myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your query here.

Comment: Just made the question a bit clearer to understand. Adding some code would be a good idea @João Domingues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for an array/collection, and not an Eloquent query, you can use the collection `keyBy` method to get unique values.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby

```php
$data = [
    [
        "Title" => "A",
        "Publication date" => "2013",
    ],
    [
        "Title" => "B",
        "Publication date" => "2010",
    ],
    [
        "Title" => "B",
        "Publication date" => "2999",
    ],
    [
        "Title" => "B",
        "Publication date" => "5555",
    ],
];

$collection = collect($data)->keyBy('Title');
```

Then your output will look like this:

```php
Collection {#1389 
  #items: array:2 [
    "A" => array:2 [
      "Title" => "A"
      "Publication date" => "2013"
    ]
    "B" => array:2 [
      "Title" => "B"
      "Publication date" => "5555"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The `keyBy` method will give you the last item in the collection for each Title, so you can sort the collection before calling `keyBy` if you want to get specific items:

```php
// get each Title with the highest Publication date
$collection = collect($data)->sortBy('Publication date')->keyBy('Title');

// get each Title with the lowest Publication date
$collection = collect($data)->sortByDesc('Publication date')->keyBy('Title');
```

If you want to get back an array without the keys "A" and "B" then you can do this:

```php
$collection = collect($data)->keyBy('Title')->values()->toArray();
```

Output:

```php
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "A"
    "Publication date" => "2013"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "B"
    "Publication date" => "5555"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing crazy loops trying to remove / push , tried everything. Only 1 line of code does all the thing lol thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `destinct` and `groupBy` in your query.

Comment: this is an array i've built couldn't use distinct because data is coming from different sources